# break-inside: avoid; cleanly wrap around position: absolute; Header and Footer

Tags: html, css

I'm using a Chromium based browser. My goal is to set up a printable report composed of variably-sized divs that fit inside a fixed header and footer that is required on each page. This is the code I've written as an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 12px;
            padding: 12px;
            width: 256px;
        }

        header {
            border-style: solid;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            height: 128px;
            border-color: blue;
        }

        div {
            border-style: solid;
            height: 128px;
            break-inside: avoid;
        }

        footer {
            border-style: solid;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            height: 128px;
            border-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header> </header>

    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>

    <footer> </footer>
</body>
```

It looks fine when I'm rendering it in the browser. However, when I go to print my results, it looks like this:

[image: Rendered Example]

How could I format my code such that the black boxes (div) do not overlap with the Header and Footer elements?, but instead cleanly render below the header on the next page? Is this possible using only CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Your header and footer use `position: absolute;`, but you can turn it of with `@media print` (It was designed for it).

```
@media print { 
  header,
  footer {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for what I need it to. While the overlapping issue has been fixed, now the header and footer don't act like headers and footers and stick to the bottom of the page / appear on every page. I'm looking for the header and footer to act as expected, while the inside boxes wrap around them.

Comment: @EthanHill the key information in my post is `@media print`. I would try appending in that mode `body { padding-top: [headerHeight]; padding-bottom: [footerHeight] }` then you can position then absolutely without overlapping - I'm not sure if they will be repeated, but with `@media print` you can style your document.

Comment: I tried to add padding to the body element within the @media print styling. It did not do what I need it to. The padding only works at the top and bottom of the element on not on each page. It also affects the header and footer, which have had their functionality (appearing on each page) broken. I'm going to have to find something else. Thank you for your time, though.